# iOS: rendering a subview at the proper resolution

Tags: ios, render, drawrect, cgaffinetransform, setneedsdisplay

I have a view which has a few subviews. I am using transforms to scale the view 400%, which works perfectly, but I am not sure how to scale the "drawing" of the sub-views. So when I render the scaled view the subviews come out fuzzy because their drawing is still at 100%.

I have tried `[view setNeedsDisplay]` on the view and its subViews, but the drawing is still low resolution.

Any ideas on how to fix this render?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Why not use the setFrame method with autoresizing for subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CGFloat myScale = 4.0;
[view setContentScaleFactor:myScale*[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]]];
```

Additionally, if you were embedding your view within a UIScrollView to allow the user to zoom in/out you could put this implementation in your UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    scale *= [[[scrollView window] screen] scale];
    [view setContentScaleFactor:scale];
}
```